# PnP-X and automatic installation of network storage to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, upnp, zeroconf, nas

I tested successfully with Linux by using Avahi(Bonjour) and Netatalk(AFP) to provide network storage to Mac OS X seamlessly (as like Time Capsule).

I want to make one another question for Windows 7. As I searched Windows 7 uses PnP-X and UPnP to provide Bonjour like zero configuration experience. What I want to achieve is:

1. Use Samba on Linux to share one folder
2. Publish this shared folder as NAS service by using PnP-X and UPnP
3. If a Windows 7 PC attached to the LAN which have the Linux it will discover the NAS service on Linux
4. Windows 7 automatically initiate PnP install process and new disk volume will be appeared on Explorer without any user intervention. This new volume is actually Samba shared folder from Linux

Do you think this scenario is achievable by using PnP-X and how can I do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked about it by myself.

PnP-X uses [SSDP (Simple Service Discovery Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) of UPnP to publish network attached device to Windows clients in local network. By using XML configuration file of SSDP, device can let client knows PnP H/W ID.

From Windows 7, user can see PnP-X enabled device from network explorer. User can select install context menu to initiate device driver installation of PnP-X device.

PnP driver installation depends on H/W ID which is known by SSDP XML configuration file.

To implement this scenario on Linux O.S., I can use [GUPnP library](http://gupnp.org/) to support SSDP notify.
Also, I need to implement proper INF file and device driver.

BR,
Wonil.