# Create a jar file using compiled class files and an existing MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, jar, compilation

Is it possible to take existing `.class` files and a `MANIFEST.MF` to create a jar file?

Is there a library that can create a "valid" jar-file? I tried it manually and it didn't work (using 7zip). 
ERROR: "Invalid or corrupt jar file"

If everything has been compiled before, it should (in my understanding) theoretically work, if you create a new zip file, put all the files in it in the original structure and then rename it to "jar".

My idea is to program something like this with java code. A solution where I could add a file to an existing jar, would also be ok.

---

If you're interested in why I want to use this, look at my initial question: [Compile javacode out of a running java accpilaction - on a system that hasn't JDK installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417752/compile-javacode-out-of-a-running-java-accpilaction-on-a-system-that-hasnt-jd/22417802?noredirect=1#comment34103071_22417802)

Comment: Have you tried using `jar` command that is distributed with the JDK? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg: I have to calculate with computers that just will have jre installed. :)

Comment: So what can we expect from the computers OS? Linux? osX? Windows?

Comment: It is possible if you have no special options in your Zipper. You must not use the 7z format. Use simple ZIP. The manifest belongs in the META-INF directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977663/java-code-to-create-a-jar-file

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg: It should be as platform independent as possible. :) But it'll be windows, if other OS' would be involved, I have to look for other options. But important is, that it will run on windows.

Comment: Comment above show how to do it in java code...

Answer (score 0):

Well Jar -cf

Try the jar command in $JAVA_HOME/bin

$JAVA_HOME is the path to you JRE/JDK installation